# Jest not defined in Travis CI when deploying Docusaurus v2 to GitHub pages

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, travis-ci, github-pages, docusaurus

I'm currently working to setup a Docusaurus v2 site on GitHub pages. I have written my own Jest and Enzyme tests for my own components. Currently Jest is listed as a `devDependency` and my `.travis.yml` is as follows:

```yaml
# .travis.yml
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '10'
branches:
  only:
    - master
cache:
  npm: true
install:
  npm i
script:
  - git config --global user.name "${GH_NAME}"
  - git config --global user.email "${GH_EMAIL}"
  - echo "machine github.com login ${GH_NAME} password ${GH_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc
  - npm t && GIT_USER="${GH_NAME}" npm run deploy
```

I have updated my `package.json` scrips section to call jest relative to `node_modules` like so:

```
"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --detectOpenHandles"
```

This runs absolutely fine in travis and I see all my tests pass. The issue I am having is when it attempts to deploy the site to GitHub pages, as seen on the last line of the `scripts` section in `.travis.yml`: `npm t && GIT_USER="${GH_NAME}" npm run deploy`. I subsequently receive the following error:

```sh
ReferenceError: jest is not defined
(undefined) ReferenceError: jest is not defined
    at Module.module.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (main:26124:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (main:21:30)
    at Promise.resolve.then (main:79206:682)
Error: Failed to compile with errors.
    at compiler.run (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/commands/build.js:37:24)
    at finalCallback (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:254:12)
    at runWithDependencies.err (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:277:6)
    at done (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2931:13)
    at runCompilers (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:181:48)
    at err (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:188:7)
    at compiler.run (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:270:7)
    at finalCallback (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:257:39)
    at hooks.done.callAsync.err (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:273:13)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:42:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at onCompiled (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:271:21)
    at hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:681:15)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at compilation.seal.err (/home/travis/build/myorg/myrepository/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:678:31)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-repository@1.0.0 deploy: `docusaurus deploy`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-repository@1.0.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I might be wrong but I believe this is because my tests are being deployed as part of the codebase and as jest is a `devDependency` it does not exist at this stage; hence webpack can't find it when it's used in my `*.spec.js` files, i.e. `jest.mock(...)`. Therefore, adding jest as a normal dependency I think could fix this, although as you can appreciate that's not ideal nor the right approach. For reference I do not have my test files in `__TESTS__` or any form of test directory. As I've followed the container pattern all my spec files are adjacent to what they are testing. The structure of which is similar to this:

```
components
  - Header
    - HeaderComponent.js
    - HeaderComponent.spec.js
    - HeaderContainer.js
    - HeaderContainer.spec.js
    - Header.module.css
```

***Quick sidenote:*** *Not all my components have containers thanks to react hooks, but a few do utilise multiple bits of state, event handlers etc; in these instances, I feel it cleaner to split them into a container.*

Is there a better way for me to fix this other than making jest a regular dependency? The setup I am after is:

1. User raises pull request & Travis builds branch (only passing PRs to be merged).
2. Once PR has landed in master Travis runs above scripts and deploys to Github pages.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docusaurus maintainer here!

It's weird that webpack is picking up the test files. Did you put the components in the pages directory? If so, it might cause Docusaurus to be thinking that the tests are pages itself.

Is your repo public? Sharing it would definitely help. All JS files within `src/pages` will become routes so do make sure that all JS files within `src/pages` can be turned into pages and export a React component. Your `components` directory isn't within `src/pages`. It should be in `src/components`.

Comment: I do have my components with in `src/components` yes, although from what you've said I've discovered the issue was I had a spec file for `pages/index.js` which was `src/pages/index.spec.js`. Moving this test file out of here has fixed the build

Comment: Awesome, I'll add a note to the docs to warn people about this.